# Obtaining URL of notebook which has been published using "Save or Publish" button

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

If I use "Save or Publish" button in top right, it uploads notebook and gives me URL of location. What if I forget the location, is there a way to retrieve the ULR later for that notebook?

My current pattern is to copy-paste the following cell into beginning of every notebook. When I run it, it publishes the notebook and inserts URL of the location into the notebook. It's a bit cumbersome.

```
(* deploys with canonical name *)
deploy := Module[{notebookFn, parentDir, cloudFn, result},
   Print[DateString[]];
   notebookFn = FileNameSplit[NotebookFileName[]][[-1]];
   parentDir = FileNameSplit[NotebookFileName[]][[-2]];
   cloudFn = parentDir~StringJoin~"/"~StringJoin~notebookFn;
   result = 
    CloudDeploy[SelectedNotebook[], CloudObject[cloudFn], 
     Permissions -> "Public", SourceLink -> None];
   Print["Uploading to ", cloudFn];
   result
   ];
deploy
```

Comment: I can see mine under my `Mathematica Online` account. Is that not the case for you?

Comment: I can see it, but this takes too many clicks, so wanted a programmatic way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of all cloud objects with [`CloudObjects`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudObjects.html). Also, `CloudObjects["dir"]` returns all cloud objects in given directory `"dir"`.

Then, you can use `First` to extract the URL.

```
First /@ CloudObjects[]

(* {"https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/domen/Base", 
    "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/domen/Desktop", 
    "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/domen/Document1.nb", 
    "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/domen/Document2.nb", 
    "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/domen/Published",
    "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/domen/trash", 
    "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/domen/userEIWLs"} *)

First /@ CloudObjects["Desktop"]
(* {"https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/domen/Desktop/Document3.nb"} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I can use this to do this to get the published name: ```fn[s_] := Last@FileNameSplit[s];
Select[CloudObjects["Published"], 
 fn@First@# == fn@NotebookFileName[] &]```